# What does it mean to predict "with a constant" in a decision tree?

Tags: regression, cart

I'm new to this exchange and ML. Below is a snippet (hopefully it's enough context) from *The Elements of Statistical Learning* by Hastie, Tibshirani, Friedman:

> We first split the space into
>   two regions, and model the response by the mean of $Y$ in each region.
>   We choose the variable and split-point to achieve the best fit. Then one
>   or both of these regions are split into two more regions, and this process
>   is continued, until some stopping rule is applied. For example, in the top
>   right panel of Figure 9.2, we first split at $X_1 = t_1$. Then the region $X_1 ≤ t_1$
>   is split at $X_2 = t_2$ and the region $X_1 > t_1$ is split at $X_1 = t_3$. Finally, the
>   region $X_1 > t_3$ is split at $X_2 = t_4$. The result of this process is a partition
>   into the five regions $R_1,R_2, . . . ,R_5$ shown in the figure. The corresponding
>   regression model predicts $Y$ with a constant $c_m$ in region $R_m$, that is, 
>   $$
> \hat{f}(X)=\sum_{}^{} c_m I\{(X_1, X_2) \in R_m \}
> $$

As far as I can tell, $I\{ \}$ was not defined in any of the sentences or sections above, so being new to ML as well, I don't get what that function is.
Also, what does "predict Y with a constant" mean? Please explain at an intro level; I've just began ML and our course goes ridiculously fast so despite the notation, I don't really know what's going on.

For now I'm assuming $I$ is what we call the binary function, where it's 1 if true and 0 if false but then I'm not sure what it means for $(X_1,X_2)$ to be in $R_m$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to CV!

In the literature, $I\{A\}$ is an indicator function, i.e. (like you said) a function which is equal to 1 if the condition $A$ is true, 0 otherwise.

As it's mentioned in the snipped you posted, $R_i$ is a region of the $X_1\times X_2$ space. These regions are non overlapping, and each one has an assigned constant value $c_i$ (usually the mean, or the median of the points in that region).

For a new point $X = (X_1,X_2)$, the indicator function will be non-zero only if $X_1, X_2$ belong to the given region $R_i$, which means that the corresponding prediction will be the constant $c_i$

[image]